# Is buddypress a suitable CMS for a site with these functions?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Hi Programming Gurus,

I’m setting up a website and will need the following functions. From what I’ve research about BuddyPress, it should be able to achieve these but I’ll like to seek advice from you guys with experience working on the buddypress platform.

My site is basically:

1)       A matching site with 2 types of users (buyers/sellers)

Buyers post assignments. Sellers has a profile page with their CV and past jobs they accepted from the site.
2)       Sellers are able to see a job and press ‘apply’ to try for a job and their application gets sent to the buyer.

3)       Sellers and buyers can message one another via the platform 
(Admins like myself has the ability to approve messages. To screen out messages where direct contact information is passed between users)

4)       Enable log in via Facebook.

5)       Verification via SMS, Facebook, Linkedin and Twitter to ensure that the buyers and sellers are real people and to ensure that the contact information that is sent to both parties afterward is accurate. (I’ve found a PHP script for this on CodeCanyon, but im not sure whether it can be integrated onto Buddypress)

Do you guys think that a buddypress CMS is suitable for a site with these functions? Or should I engage a company and do custom coding? Or is that other CMS that is more suitable for my site needs?

On a separate note, if you:
a)       Know of any reliable freelancer who has experience creating a similar site. (I’m looking to hire to create some of the functions and customize some premium plugins for my site’s needs)

b)      Any plugins that can achieve the functions that I need for my site (Can be either paid or free plugins)

Do share your advice and experience! Thank you!

Comment: Any wordpress gurus or experienced users out there who can share your experience?

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress itselft wont provide exactly what you want, but it will give you a nice platform for what you are going to do.
For the features you mentioned, you need several different plugins for that,
For 1. BuddyPress dosen't have user types like that, but I developed a paid plugin for that few months ago
http://rimonhabib.com/buddypress-user-account-type-pro-has-been-released/

For 2, you need a job board section, wordpress, buddypress dont have something like that. you may either use job board plugin ( premium )
http://wpjobboard.net/
or this can be easily develop using wordpress custom post type. but of course, need to be manage access for different types of users based buddypress user account type plugin

For 3.  BuddyPress has nice messaging system, but it has no moderation system, so, by default admin can't see whats passing between buyer and seller. and it seems theres no plugin for that too.

For 4. You can use wp-fb-connect plugin, it is buddypress supported and both have free and premium version

For 5. Yes, the item you have seen in CodeCanyon is work with BuddyPress too.

So, BuddyPress is a good basement for what you want, but of course need customization.